# yii access control filter rules in controllers

Tags: yii

When writing rules for access control in yii controllers, possible parameters to be set
for a rule are 'action' - sets to which action the rule applies; 'users', 'roles', etc.

Now, both the yii guide (pdf) and reference (I have chm file) say that it's possible to set,
also, a controller id for the controller the rule should apply to.

Now, if we are already putting these rules in a controller class/file, how would we be able
to put some other controller (other than the current one) as the parameter here, meaning
how would some other controller whose id we mention here - how would it know there is a rule that applies to it, since it's written in a completely other controller class/file?

How would the controller be aware of a rule that mentions it, if it's written outside of it,
in a completely different controller?

Comment: Did any of our answers solve your question? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hook into CWebApplication::beforeControllerAction() to apply filters before the controller even gets the request.

~thinkt4nk

Comment: Can you please detail your answer? How can I hook into beforeControllerAction method? Can you make an example please??

Answer (score 3):

One case where you could use this is if you set some rules in a base controller and extend it. Maybe you have some admin-only controllers, then you can save a little code by just adding these rules into a base Controller that all other controllers extend?

Also, this might be used if you are attaching Behaviors to the controller?

I've never used this rule though, I'm just hypothesizing. :)

Answer (score 0):

Dear Friend,
Yii give us 3 type of user groups 
(*)- for All(guest),
(@)- for registered,
(admin)- for super user we can use it from Controller / public function accessRules()

add if you wanna custom user rights than u can also use 
1)ttp://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-user-management/
and u can also use "Yii-Rights" which is best for customization
2)http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/10556-extension-rights/page_*p*_51869#entry51869

Regard,
Bhavik Chauhan

Comment: @- for registered & authenticated users